# Is existence of adjunction between $a\otimes{-}$ and $b\otimes{-}$ enough for duality?

Tags: duality-theorems, monoidal-categories

Let $(\mathfrak{C},\otimes,1)$ be a monoidal category. An object $a$ is dual to $b$ if there exist evaluation $ev\colon a\otimes b\to 1$ and coevaluation $coev\colon 1\to b\otimes a$ morphisms satifying $(ev\otimes a)\circ (a\otimes coev)=id_a$ and $(b\otimes ev)\circ (coev\otimes b)=id_b$.

Using the unit-counit description of adjunctions, one easily sees that this implies the existence of adjunctions:
$$(1) ~a\otimes {-} ~\colon \mathfrak{C}\to \mathfrak{C}\colon  b\otimes {-}$$
$$(2) ~{-}\otimes b ~\colon \mathfrak{C}\to \mathfrak{C}\colon  {-}\otimes a$$

However, we know additionally that these adjunctions are compatible with $\otimes$. To clarify: consider e.g. the adjuntion isomorphism $Hom(a\otimes x,y)\cong Hom(x,b\otimes y)$, let $f\colon a\otimes x\to y$ and let $g\colon x\to b\otimes y$ be the adjoint morphism. Then the adjoint of $f\otimes id_z$ is $g\otimes id_z$.

So it seems to me that having a duality beween $a$ and $b$ is stronger than merely having a pair of adjunctions (1) and (2).

I am searching for an example in the literature which shows that the two phenomena are different, or a proof of equivalence of the two.